# Is it possible to send update notification to app users iOS

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, app-store

I have an application which is already LIVE on app store. Is it possible to send update notification to all the users whenever the new update is available?

Comment: which notification source are you using?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren for update app instead of notification it will work while user will open app and new version will available on app store.

Comment: Yesss obviously... For that you can also set code for version comaprision and show popup.  I have code for it.

Comment: @JatinRB we should avoid third libraries when it could be done with few lines of code.

Comment: @Kudos ok thanks. personally i will prefer the code from our side. but i think as the new guy he will have some difficulty to understood that's why i suggest him a library

Comment: I want to send push notification to users, not the popups inside application. Please guide in this direction.

Comment: @JatinRB he already mentioned that his app is live, Obviusly he is not beginner.

Comment: sorry bro my bad :)

Comment: @Kudos can u plz share code snippet for version comparison and so on?

Comment: Sure @MuhammadSharjeel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for **App Version Comparision** is:

```
 func checkAppUpdateAvailability(onSuccess: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, onError: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
              let curentVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
              let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.facebook.app") else {
            return onError(true)
        }
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [.allowFragments]) as? [String: Any] else {
               return onError(true)
            }
            if let result = (json["results"] as? [Any])?.first as? [String: Any], let appStoreVersion = result["version"] as? String {
                print("version in app store", appStoreVersion," current Version ",curentVersion);
                let versionCompare = curentVersion.compare(appStoreVersion, options: .numeric)
                if versionCompare == .orderedSame {
                    onSuccess(false)
                } else if versionCompare == .orderedAscending {
                    onSuccess(true)
                    // 2.0.0 to 3.0.0 is ascending order, so ask user to update
                }
            }
        } catch {
            onError(true)
        }
    }
```

Now you can check App Update.

```
checkAppUpdateAvailability { (status) in
            //When status == true show popup.
        } onError: { (status) in
            // Handle error
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Sometimes this url return the previous app version. So it redirecting app store again and again after the update. Any solution for that?

Comment: I am sorry But I am already using it and Its working damn fine... Please share your code and iOS Version...

Comment: I have used the same code you written. It worked perfect in iPhone 6. But in iPhone 11 it return previous version no.